# iOS UIView derived view instance drawRect being called but not updating on screen?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiview

Was hoping someone could help with this please? I've scanned through the forum and apple docs and can't find anything that matches my problem exactly.

I'm trying to animate a custom 'Composite' UIView derived class (with overidden drawRect) by changing a custom colour property (*not* one of the standard view properties like centre, alpha, backgroundColour etc), calling setNeedsDisplay and redrawing the view using drawRect over X seconds duration to produce a slow colour change from say, red to blue.

At the moment, all Composite::drawRect does internally is clear the context (the view has a default background colour set to clear) and fill the view using the colour provided. This works fine the first time it's called - the view appears on screen in the correct red colour.

My problem is that when I try to animate the view by updating the colour property, even though drawRect is being called everytime I call setNeedsDisplay and the colour being fed into the view instance is correct the view doesn't update *on screen* until I stop calling setNeedsDisplay (or rather, stop updating the custom view colour property). It's like every call to setNeedsDisplay pushes the view to the back of a list so it doesn't get updated on screen until it stops getting called (even though drawRect is being called).

For example - trying to change the colour from red to blue over 10 seconds, the view stays red for 10 seconds, then turns to blue in a single frame at the end of the property changing (and presumably when I stop calling setNeedsDisplay) rather than a slow fade between the two over the time duration.

Any ideas what's going on? I'm guessing I need to animate this using apple's own animation property stuff but I'd really prefer not to - I'm trying to make this cross platform if possible and I don't see why my own method shouldn't work.

The basics:

In case it matters, my composite view instance is a subview of an UIImageView. (I know imageview drawRect doesn't get called but I can't imagine this is a problem for it's subviews - after all, my Composite::drawRect is definitely being called).

I'm setting the right colour on my view instance - I've debug printed this to be sure - so the colour provided to the view goes from red to blue over however many seconds / frames.

I'm setting setNeedsDispay and drawRect is being called every time - again, debug printing confirms this.

This is happening over multiple frames and the app goes through the drawing update at the end of every frame - I.e I'm not blocking the render thread or anything - the app runs fine, it just doesn't update the view on screen even though its drawRect is being called, until I stop manipulating the property. Someone mentioned a similar problem where they were blocking the render thread in a single frame but I'm definitely not doing anything like that.

I've tried messing around with the following but they all produced the same results (i.e. view changed from red to blue in a single frame rather than a slow change over).

- Updating the colour every frame but only calling setNeedsDisplay on my view every Xth frame (5, 10, 20, 30 etc)
- Updating the colour every frame but not calling setNeedsDisplay unless the corresponding drawRect call from the last setNeedsDisplay has happened (i.e. set a flag to false in SetColour func, set same flag to true in drawRect, test against it when decided to call setNeedsDisplay) - same results.
- setting the view bounds with ContentMode set to redraw to force an update - same results
- tried calling setNeedsDisplay on the parent image view too - no change.

I'm guessing that this just isn't possible - can anyone explain why its not updating the v view onscreen even though drawRect is being called? Any ideas how I should do this? I don't think I would be able to do what I want to do if I tried animated one of the default view properties using apple's internal animation system but if I've got to use that....

Thanks!

:-)

Comment: Can we see some code, please?

Comment: Sure - will add it tonight when I get home :)

Comment: After pulling the offending code into a separate project for posting on here, it worked fine (lol). It turned about to be a simple mistake with the colour generation where the debug printf's were correct but the actual colour values were wrong. Live and learn! :D